# How can you use a collection to create root-level menu items in a ContextMenu?

Tags: wpf, contextmenu, itemscontrol

We have a collection of DesignerLocation objects stored in a property of our ViewModel. We would like context menus to be created for each item so the user can access them easily.

Currently, we're binding that collection to the Items property of a specific 'Open...' context menu, meaning the user has to flyout that menu, even if there is only one designer location.

e.g. Here's an over-simplified version of our context menu with three designer locations

```
Open in... (<-- This menu's Items property is bound to DesignerLocations)
    Open DesignerLocation1
    Open DesignerLocation2
    Open DesignerLocation3
[separator]
Cut
Copy
Paste
```

Now here's the same context menu with only one designer location. This creates an unnecessary flyout to a single item.

```
Open in...
    Open DesignerLocation1
[separator]
Cut
Copy
Paste
```

This is what we *really* want...

```
Open DesignerLocation1
Open DesignerLocation2
Open DesignerLocation3
[separator]
Cut
Copy
Paste
```

...and if there is only one...

```
Open DesignerLocation1
[separator]
Cut
Copy
Paste
```

That said, how could one implement something like the following without having to resort to composite collections or responding manually to ContextMenuOpening?

```
<MenuCollectionPlaceholder>  <-- This would be bound to DesignerLocations and would generate MenuItems as needed without requiring the flyout
[separator]
Cut
Copy
Paste
```

Finally, I have seen people literally place ItemsControls directly within context menus, but this just seems wrong to me since an ItemsControl itself is not a MenuItem.  Is it wrong?  That would give us what we're after.

```
<ItemsControl>  <-- This would be bound to DesignerLocations and would generate MenuItems as needed without requiring the flyout
[separator]
Cut
Copy
Paste
```